# Multiple Key Value Query Search Input Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not quite sure exactly what to search for or where exactly to start, but I'm trying to see if it's possible to have a customized search box for multiple GET queries simply using jQuery, JS, HTML and CSS.

[image]

The user would first type in something which will prompt the red box to show (key) and it would autofill with a listed default given the first few characters they typed. Then upon pressing enter or tab, they would be allowed to fill in the answer gray box (value). Then after, they can either choose to submit or put in another key / value.

Is there a jQuery library that already has this implemented, and is this even possible? I thought about putting input boxes inside the input search box and using jQuery to hide and show them depending on what they type, but is that the best way?

I'd like to do this without comprehensive framework / library like Angular and React.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @AssafMuller I ended up writing my own.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

You must handle it with one of JavaScript freamworks like Vue.js, React.js or Angular.js