# Looking for an example of a form sending user specified values from auto-completed keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'd like to build a form that allows the user to select from pre-defined keys with auto completion, e.g. a search box:
https://select2.org/selections

The trick is that once a key is selected, the user should be able to input a value for that key. Once submitted the form will send key/value pairs.

The amount of keys is dynamic and could go up to 100 or 200.

From a design perspective, can anyone think of an example of a website that does something like this? From a technical perspective, how would you achieve this?

This question is similar to [Multiple Key Value Query Search Input Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913668/multiple-key-value-query-search-input-box), only that question never got an answer and I'm also looking for ideas or examples from a design perspective.

Essentially something similar to: querybuilder.js.org/demo.html. However I only need a subset of that functionality: It should all be exact match, only support 'AND', no need for groups, and the keys should support autocompletion. Ideally, the user could control the entire thing solely with his keyboard, and wouldn't require a mouse to add new filters.

Comment: I don't actually understand what you want so I can't give you any advice.

Comment: Essentially something similar to: http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html.

However I only need a subset of that functionality: It should all be exact match, only support 'AND', no need for groups, and the keys should support autocompletion. Ideally, the user could control the entire thing solely with his keyboard, and wouldn't require a mouse to add new filters.

Comment: Oh right... had to build one of those last year for a survey... good luck. I don't really think there is going to be a library you can just use, I had to make my own custom one, you might have to do the same. I would suggest just start playing around with a basic idea and ask again when you have some code going

Answer (score 0):

Have implemented a sample

```js
function AutoComplete(){
  return {
     "apple":'',
     "cherry":'',
     "watermelon": ''
  }
}

function genListItem(key){
  return "<li data-item='"+key+"'>"+key+"</li>";
}

function generateList(data){
  var keys = Object.keys(data);
  var list=[];
  list.push("<ul>");
  keys.forEach(function(key){
       list.push(genListItem(key));
  });
  list.push("</ul>");
  return list.join('');
}

function generateTag(key){
  var span=[];
  span.push("<span class='tagContainer'>");
  span.push("<span>"+key+": </span>");
  span.push("<span><input type='text' class='tagInput' name='"+key+"'/></span>");
  span.push("<span class='closeBtn'><i class='fa fa-times-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>")
  span.push("</span>");
  return span.join('');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').on('click', function(){
        var json = AutoComplete();
        $("#autocomplete").html(generateList(json))
  });
  
  $("#autocomplete").on('click', 'li', function(){
     var data = $(this).data('item');
     $('#search').append(generateTag(data));
  });
  
  $("#search").on('click','.closeBtn', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
  });
  
});
```

```css
#search {
  min-width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position:relative;
}
.tagContainer{
  height: 30px;
  line-height:30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  background: #eee;
}
.tagContainer:hover {
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
}
.tagInput {
  width:50px;
  height: 20px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.closeBtn {
  width:24px;
  top:10px;
  right:0;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:5px;
  padding:2px 2px;
  font-size:14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' />
</head>
<body>

  <div id="search"></div>
  <div id='autocomplete'>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```